# Importing properties from different build files for Ant

Tags: ant, properties, import

I have 2 build files into separate projects,

- build_common.xml,
- build.xml which is the main build file.

I am trying to import a property from build_common.xml without importing the whole file. Is there a way to do that if I know the path to the build_common.xml?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you want to import the whole file?

Comment: Well I am not sure what is going to be the impact of doing that. Both builds are quite complex and there were not meant to be mixed. So I just want to invoke some ant targets and move some files... The target invocation is quite simple but for moving the files I need to know their names, paths,... - which are declared into the properties. That's what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to import certain properties, they probably SHOULD be in separate files (broken apart by common use).  That said, maybe one of your ant tasks could use grep, or some other collection of utilities to transform build_common.xml into a NEW file, that only contains what you want, and then import THAT?

I really don't think it's the BEST way to approach the problem, but I think it could work.

Comment: Ok I understand you point but I have more projects that are depending on the build_common.xml and the build.xml is for a new project that requires that some of the other projects are build. Anyway I am trying to make this as simple as possible and that import property would be the best option if it is possible. Thanks!